# How to switch to the newly opened window using nodejs puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am having some difficulty getting puppeteer to switch its focus to the newly opened window.

The following is what my program is trying to do:
I am trying to use puppeteer to interact with Google Tag Manager preview window but I can't get it to interact with the newly opened window after clicking the submit button.

My puppeteer code is doing the following (please see screenshots below for more details):

1. go to https://tagassistant.google.com/#!#source=TAG_MANAGER&id=GTM-XXXXX&gtm_auth=kALKj04OP-SpPs2dMA70Tw&gtm_preview=env-562&cb=428326580326923
2. fill in the hostname to preview e.g. https://www.theage.com.au
3. click Start button
4. click on a menu item on the newly opened window (https://www.theage.com.au)

Puppeteer successfully perform up to step 3, however it failed at step 4 because (my first theory of the cause) its focus is still on the current window (if you do it manually on the browser, after clicking the start button, another window of the test site e.g. [www.loreal.com.au](http://www.loreal.com.au) will be opened).

My second theory of the cause: I also suspect it does not successfully click on the Start button because when I tried to take screenshot of puppeteer action, I can see the start button is grayed out even though the test hostname has been filled so I had to overcome that by telling it to manipulate the DOM attribute of the button to remove the "disabled" to make the button clickable. However, I'm not exactly sure if it successfully clicks through or not.

Could someone show me how to switch puppeteer focus to the newly opened window?

Thank you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQxX7.png)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown any code, so it's hard to pinpoint where the problem is. But in general, you might want to wait for popup event:

```js
const waitForWindow = new Promise(resolve => page.on('popup', resolve));

await page.click('.my-link');
const newPage = await waitForWindow;

// now I can interact with the new page
const linksInnerTexts = await newPage.$$eval('a', links => links.map(l => l.innerText));
```

This is a working example if your link has `target="_blank"` attribute, which opens a new page in a new tab. It also works if your link looks somthing like `target="popup" onclick="window.open('../html-link.htm','name','width=600,height=400')`, which opens a page in a new window.

Comment: There is also a useful event ['targetcreated'](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#event-targetcreated).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys,

I have managed to get it working using the targetcreated event.

```
        browser.on('targetcreated', async (target) => { //This block intercepts all new events
      if (target.type() === 'page') {               // if it tab/page
             //const page = await target.page();      // declare it
             const page = await target.page();      // declare it
             const url = page.url();                // example, look at her url
             console.log('***** ' + url);

             //.....
      }
    });
```